# BlackBerry parsing UTF-8 XML File with SAX Parser

Tags: java, blackberry, utf-8, xml-parsing, saxparser

I am trying to parse a UTF-8 xml file using SAX parser and i used the parser but it results an exception it's message "Expecting an element"

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<config>
<filepath>/mnt/sdcard/Audio_Recorder/anonymous22242.3gp</filepath>
<filename>anonymous22242.3gp</filename>
<annotation>
    <file>anonymous22242.3gp</file>
    <timestamp>0:06</timestamp>
    <note>test1</note>
</annotation>
<annotation>
    <file>anonymous22242.3gp</file>
    <timestamp>0:09</timestamp>
    <note>لول</note>
</annotation>
<annotation>
    <file>anonymous22242.3gp</file>
    <timestamp>0:09</timestamp>
    <note>لولو</note>
</annotation>
</config>
```

```
     private static String fileDirectory;
private final static ArrayList<String> allFileNames = new ArrayList<String>();
private final static ArrayList<String[]> allAnnotations = new ArrayList<String[]>();
private static String[] currentAnnotation = new String[3];

public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
try {

    SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser playbackParser = factory.newSAXParser();

    DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {

        boolean audioFullPath = false;
        boolean audioName = false;
        boolean annotationFile = false;
        boolean annotationTimestamp = false;
        boolean annotationNote = false;

        public void startElement(String uri, String localName,
                String qName, Attributes attributes)
                throws SAXException {

            System.out.println("Start Element :" + qName);

            if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("filepath")) {
                audioFullPath = true;
            }

            if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("filename")) {
                audioName = true;
            }

            if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("file")) {
                annotationFile = true;
            }

            if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("timestamp")) {
                annotationTimestamp = true;
            }

            if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("note")) {
                annotationNote = true;
            }

        }

        public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
                String qName) throws SAXException {

            System.out.println("End Element :" + qName);

        }

        public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length)
                throws SAXException {

            if (audioFullPath) {
                String filePath = new String(ch, start, length);
                System.out.println("Full Path : " + filePath);
                fileDirectory = filePath;
                audioFullPath = false;
            }

            if (audioName) {
                String fileName = new String(ch, start, length);
                System.out.println("File Name : " + fileName);
                allFileNames.add(fileName);
                audioName = false;
            }

            if (annotationFile) {
                String fileName = new String(ch, start, length);
                currentAnnotation[0] = fileName;
                annotationFile = false;
            }

            if (annotationTimestamp) {
                String timestamp = new String(ch, start, length);
                currentAnnotation[1] = timestamp;
                annotationTimestamp = false;
            }
            if (annotationNote) {
                String note = new String(ch, start, length);
                currentAnnotation[2] = note;
                annotationNote = false;
                allAnnotations.add(currentAnnotation);
            }

        }

    };

    InputStream inputStream = getStream("http://www.example.com/example.xml");
    Reader xmlReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");

    InputSource xmlSource = new InputSource(xmlReader);
    xmlSource.setEncoding("UTF-8");

    playbackParser.parse(xmlSource, handler);

    System.out.println(fileDirectory);
    System.out.println(allFileNames);
    System.out.println(allAnnotations);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}

public Static InputStream getStream(String url)
{
    try
    {
        connection = getConnection(url);
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",System.getProperty("microedition.profiles"));
        connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=UTF-8");

        inputStream = connection.openInputStream();
        return inputStream;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("NNNNNNN "+e.getMessage());

        return null;
      }

    }

 public HttpConnection getConnection(String url)
{

    try
    {
      connection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url+getConnectionString());


    }
    catch(Exception e)

    {

    }


    return connection;
}
```

but when i pass to the parse method the inputStream instead of inputSource it parses the file but still have a problem with Arabic characters between

```
playbackParser.parse(inputStream, handler);
```

Comment: "ArrayList<String>" cannot compile for a BlackBerry, as BlackBerries run only java-me.  Why is the BlackBerry tag on this?

Answer (score 1):

The XML you showed has unencoded Arabic characters in it.  That is in violation of the XML's declared Encoding, which means the XML is malformed.  A SAX parser processes data piece by piece sequentially, triggering events for each piece.  It will not detect such an encoding error until it reaches the piece that contains those erroneous characters. There is nothing you can do about that.  The XML needs to be fixed by its original author.

Comment: How must the XML be encoded when including characters from other languages?

Comment: All characters in the XML need to be encoded using the charset that is specified in the `Encoding` attribute of the XML's prolog.  In this case, the charset of your example XML is `UTF-8` (which is XML's default charset when none if specified). The Arabic characters were not UTF-8 encoded when the XML was generated, hense the error. In UTF-8, the Unicode string `لول` is encoded as byte octets `D9 84 D9 88 D9 84`, and `لولو` as `D9 84 D9 88 D9 84 D9 88`.

Comment: @Remy unfortunately, in this case, stackoverflow is a character based question-and-answer site, so it is hard to tell whether this file is encoded correctly or not, since the characters are copies from an editor after being properly converted from their filesystem representation. I don't think anyone would be happier to see the cp1252 representations of d9 84 d9 88 d9 84.

Comment: It would be useful, then, for @MohammedElsabry to take the original XML, save it to a file as-is, and post it to a public file sharing site for us to look at.  Or at least use a binary/hex editor to look at the byte octets of those two element values and post them here.